# Coefficient Inconsistency in Fixed Effects Models

Tags: fixed-effects-model

I am estimating the effect of a policy change. The policy affected industries within states different across time. So my variation is coming from industry, state, and calendar year. When I run the regressions I estimate five models. The first model has controls and all one-way fixed effects (state, industry, calendar year). In the second through fourth model in addition to controls and one-way fixed effects, I include two-way fixed effects (state-year, state-industry, industry-state) one at a time. In the fifth model I include controls, all one-way fixed effects and all two-way fixed effects. In all models the coefficients are significant and have the same sign. However, whenever the two-way state-year fixed effects are included (second and fifth model), the estimated coefficients blow up and are much higher than in the remaining models. This happens no matter how I define my independent variable (normalized or non normalized) or what outcome variable (dummy or continuous) I use. Has anyone and idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Welcome! When you say ‘state-year’ do you mean separate state *and* year fixed effects or a single ‘state-year’ effect? Just curious if you’re combining dimensions. Also, in your second and fifth models, do any dummies drop out of the model? It’s hard to tell what’s happening without seeing your output.

Comment: When I say stay-year, I mean state dummies interacted with year dummies. The single state and year fixed effects are always in the models. It's the two way fixed effects that I am iteratively including one at a time. No nothing gets dropped in my second and fifth model. I suspect it has something to do with how much variation is taken up by the two-way fixed effects. When I use state linear trends instead of state interacted with year fixed effects the coefficients increase by less. However I'd like to get a second opinion about that and maybe some references to papers why this is happening.